# Healing power requires a CD 10 to activate. Is there any bonuses to the roll?

Tags: healing, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Healing power requires a DC 10 to activate. Are there any bonuses to the roll?

Do you add your Healing rank, Treatment skill (Int + Skill Rank), or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For the Healing power, use the power's ranks for the check.

When you use your Healing power, you have to make a DC 10 check, using your ranks in the power's effect. Chapter 6, in the section "How Powers Work", subsection "Effect Checks" says the following:

> In some cases, you may be required to make an **effect check** to determine how well an effect works. A power check is just like any other check: d20, plus the power’s rank, plus any applicable modifiers, against a difficulty class set by the Gamemaster. The results of various power checks are described in this chapter.
>
> Effect Check = d20 + rank + modifiers vs. difficulty class

In this case, "Modifiers" could refers to situational modifiers, or adjustments from use of certain talents. I could not find any rules saying that your Treatment skill comes into play here.

The Treatment skill is completely separate from the Healing power, in that it doesn't necessarily have to come from powers at all. Treatment requires proper medical equipment (or else you take a -5 penalty), whereas Healing is powered by however superpowers work.  Treatment is generally used to diagnose or stabilize or provide long-term care, whereas Healing is a superpower that quickly removes unwanted conditions from a character.

Comment: If you want to compare to D&D: The Treatment skill is analogous to the Medicine skill, and the Healing power is analogous to spells like *Cure Wounds* or *Restoration*.

Comment: Sir thank for speedy and comparison to D&D which help out a lot.  But how do I add modifiers to the check. Advantage: Benefit - Spell Focus (Healing) +2 at rak 1 and (Greater Spell Focus)+5 at rank 2. Expertise: Healing rank x.

Comment: Those mechanics don't exist in mutants and masterminds. Either use stunts to temporarily boost the power, or simply invest in more ranks.

Comment: Technically speaking, the books do suggest that allowing a Conditional Bonus in certain circumstances can indeed be a 1 PP or 2 PP Advantage or Feature. That said, these bonuses are supposed to be conditional, not "my power is stronger by 2 ranks by buying a 1 PP Advantage. Some GMs might also allow Second Chance for some situations to allow for a second roll. Honestly, I've very seldom seen a Healing check fail, and they often wipe out all injuries in a single check.